# How to prevent users from seeing a blockfile directly

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Because `value` is clear text in a `blockfile`, if a user log in to a server and opens it by `cat` or `less` command, that user can see all data.
I want to prevent users from seeing a `blockfile` directly. Do you have any idea? (encryption, access control, etc.)

Comment: Before getting into it , I would suggest you to understand the **Encryption** resources , learn about packages like **BCCSP** , **BCCSPFactory**,**Entities**.- chaincode
-- fabcrypt
----- wrapper.go
----- utils.go 
--- main.go                                                                                                                              [Resource](https://www.skcript.com/svr/end-to-end-encryption-hyperledger-fabric/)

Comment: Thank you. I got a clue about my question from [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.4/examples/chaincode/go/enccc_example)

Comment: In that case, you can flag up the comment, hahaha. Just kidding . Also have you worked on block file for the private key in any application or project? I need help.